# seaborn heatmap annotation ValueError: Unknown format code 'g' for object of type 'numpy.str_'

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, seaborn, heatmap

I want to draw a [**`seaborn.heatmap`**](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.heatmap.html) and annotate only some rows/columns.
Example where all cells have annotation:

```
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np


n1 = 5
n2 = 10
M = np.random.random((n1, n2))   

fig, ax = plt.subplots()

sns.heatmap(ax = ax, data = M, annot = True)

plt.show()
```

[image]

Following [these examples](https://stackabuse.com/ultimate-guide-to-heatmaps-in-seaborn-with-python/) (paragraph ***Adding Value Annotations***), it is possible to pass to [**`seaborn.heatmap`**](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.heatmap.html) an array with annotations for each cell as `annot` parameter:

> **annot : *bool or rectangular dataset, optional***
> If True, write the data value in each cell. If an array-like with the same shape as data,
> then use this to annotate the heatmap instead of the data.
> Note that DataFrames will match on position, not index.

If I try to generate an array of `str` and pass it as `annot` parameter to [**`seaborn.heatmap`**](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.heatmap.html) I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/.../myfile.py", line 16, in <module>
    sns.heatmap(ax = ax, data = M, annot = A)
  File "C:\venv\lib\site-packages\seaborn\_decorators.py", line 46, in inner_f
    return f(**kwargs)
  File "C:\venv\lib\site-packages\seaborn\matrix.py", line 558, in heatmap
    plotter.plot(ax, cbar_ax, kwargs)
  File "C:\venv\lib\site-packages\seaborn\matrix.py", line 353, in plot
    self._annotate_heatmap(ax, mesh)
  File "C:\venv\lib\site-packages\seaborn\matrix.py", line 262, in _annotate_heatmap
    annotation = ("{:" + self.fmt + "}").format(val)
ValueError: Unknown format code 'g' for object of type 'numpy.str_'
```

Code which generates the `ValueError` (in this case I try to remove annotations of the 4<sup>th</sup> columns as an example):

```
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np


n1 = 5
n2 = 10
M = np.random.random((n1, n2))

A = np.array([[f'{M[i, j]:.2f}' for j in range(n2)] for i in range(n1)])
A[:, 3] = ''


fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize = (6, 3))

sns.heatmap(ax = ax, data = M, annot = A)

plt.show()
```

What is the cause of this error?
How can I generate a [**`seaborn.heatmap`**](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.heatmap.html) and annotate only selected rows/columns?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It is a formatting issue. Here  the `fmt = ''` is required if you are using `non-numeric` labels (defaults to: `fmt='.2g'`) which consider only for numeric values and throw an error for labels with text format.

```
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np


n1 = 5
n2 = 10
M = np.random.random((n1, n2))

A = np.array([[f'{M[i, j]:.2f}' for j in range(n2)] for i in range(n1)])
A[:, 3] = ''


fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize = (6, 3))

sns.heatmap(ax = ax, data = M, annot = A, fmt='')

plt.show()
```